# Getstream seen and unseen posts in a flat feed

Tags: getstream-io

Does Getstream support "seen" and "unseen" posts?

Essentially, I'd like to be able to show the user the number of new posts that have been posted to the feed since the last time they visited it.
After they see the new posts on the feed, reset the number of unseen posts to 0.

I'm aware that the notification feed has similar capabilities but best practices wise, it doesn't seem like a good idea to use that instead of a flat feed (maybe i'm wrong)

**UPDATE SCENARIO**

Every user has a `(global_feed_notifications:user_uuid)` that follows `(global_feed_flat:1)`

A user adds an activity to their `(user_posts_flat:user_uuid)`

The activity has a `to:["global_feed_flat:1"]`

The expectation is that `(global_feed_notifications:user_uuid)` would receive the activity as an unseen and unread notification due to a fanout.

**UPDATE**

The scenario failed.

[image: explorer for user_posts:user_uuid]

```
export function followDefaultFeedsOnStream(userapp){
    const streamClient = stream.connect(STREAM_KEY, STREAM_SECRET);

    const globalFeedNotifications = streamClient.feed(feedIds.globalFeedNotifications, userapp);
    globalFeedNotifications.follow(feedIds.globalFeedFlat, '1');
}

export function addPostToStream(userapp, post){
    const streamClient = stream.connect(STREAM_KEY, STREAM_SECRET);
    const userPosts = streamClient.feed(feedIds.userPosts, userapp);
    //expansion point: if posts are allowed to be friends only,
    //calculate the value of the 'to' field from post.friends_only or post.private

    const activity = {
        actor: `user:${userapp}`,
        verb: 'post',
        object: `post:${post.uuid}`,
        post_type: post.post_type,
        foreign_id: `foreign_id:${post.uuid}`,
        to: [`${feedIds.globalFeedFlat}:1`],
        time: new Date()
    }

    userPosts.addActivity(activity)
    .then(function(response) {
       console.log(response);
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
       console.log(err);
     });
}
```

**UPDATE**

Well I'm not sure what happened but it suddenly started working after a day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unread and unseen is only supported on notification feeds. You could set up your aggregation format to `{{ id }}` to avoid any aggregations but still leverage the power of unread and unseen indicators.

Comment: True this would work for feeds that every user is subscribed to individually. What about global feeds? A feed that everyone is subscribed to using the same id. (global_feed:1) I'd assume that marking that notification feed as seen (global_feed:1) would mark it as seen for everyone else that is looking at that feed.. maybe a better way to setup a global feed would fix this, but with the 100 update cap on the `to` field, it seems this is the only way

Comment: No you would need a (notification) feed per user following all the feeds that the global feed follows.

Comment: Understood, I posted a scenario as an update on the question. Would that work? If not, could you explain why not?

Comment: I had a chance to try out the scenario and it unfortunately didn't work. I'm not sure why but the `(global_feed_notifications:user_uuid)` doesn't receive the activities sent `to:["global_feed_flat:1"]`. in the getstream explorer there are no activities for global_feed_flat:1 (it doesnt even show up on the list of feeds) which would explain why the notification feeds aren't getting it